# Can a private MSMQ queue be renamed?

Tags: windows-server-2003, msmq

Can you rename an existing private MSMQ queue on Windows Server 2003?

Comment: I was going to suggest editing the text file in the msmq\storage\lqs directory that contains the configuration for the private file. 
After testing it, though, I found it didn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you can, but you can always deleted and create a new private queue by the name you desire can you not?

Comment: Absolutely, I was just asking for the sake of a customer.  Renaming would mean you wouldn't have to reconfigure permissions and such.

Answer (score 3):

No you can't rename a private queue.